# Java: Eclipse: Setter, Getter, and using a variable in another class

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't figure out how to get this code to work, I have to make a class Dog that has a getter and setter for age and name, and then a driver class called Kennel, whose main method instantiates and updates several Dog objects.

It should be printing out a name and an age, but it only does Name.

Here's what I have currently.

```
public class Dog{
private String dogname;
private int dogage;
public Dog(int dogAge2, String dogName2){
    this.dogage = dogAge2;
    this.dogname = dogName2;
}
public void setName(String name) {
}
public String getName() {
    return dogname;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.dogage = age;
}
public int getAge() {
    return dogage;  
}
public int getPersonYears(){
        return this.dogage*7;       
        }
}
```

and then the Kennel Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kennel{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int age;
    String name;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ( " Spot "); //Name of Dog
    name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println (" 5 " ); // Age of Dog
    age= scan.nextInt();
    Dog dog = new Dog(age, name);
    System.out.println("In human years the dog is: " + dog.getPersonYears());  
}
}
```

Comment: And how does it not work?

Comment: Are you trying to `scan` your own output?

Comment: Please could you give more details about the problem? Because I tested your code and it worked fine.

Comment: It should be printing out name and age, but I'm only getting the name.

Comment: @MaxSmith that is probably since its waiting for input after its printing the name... try to type something in the consol and hit enter! I bet you will be surprised...

Answer (score 0):

You just should write your right message like this:

```
 System.out.println ( "Enter name. "); //Name of Dog
   ...
 System.out.println ("Enter age. " ); // Age of Dog
   ...  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to `scan` your own input.

```
System.out.println ( " Spot "); // this only prints the string
name = scan.nextLine(); // this is waiting for you to enter input and assings it to "name"
System.out.println (" 5 " ); // same here
age= scan.nextInt(); // and here
```

You see after the print you need to type the input that will be assigned to your variables. You can't use `scan` on a printed by you output.